# What is the record for the most wins by a single team against a single team in an NBA season?

Tags: trivia, nba

The Milwaukee Bucks just swept the Detroit Pistons in their first round series  4 games to none after sweeping the regular season series between these two teams 4 games to none.  After completing the playoff series sweep they ended up with an 8-0 record against Detroit this season.

**Has a team ever gone 8-0 or better (combined regular season and playoffs) against a single team in a single season?**  If so, has any team ever won more than 8 games against a single team?

Notes:

- Currently it is not possible for a team to win more than 8 games against  a single team (max of 4 regular season meetings + 4 playoff wins clinches the series), I'm not sure how far back that holds true from a schedule perspective.
- With the current schedule format, teams only play divisional opponents 4 times in the regular season.  So 8-0 (at least in recent years) would need to be a case of two division rivals meeting in the playoffs.